# Confusion about happens before relationship in concurrency

Tags: c++, concurrency, memory-barriers, memory-model, stdatomic

Below is an example given in **Concurrency in Action** , and the author says the `assert` may fire, but I don't understand why.

```
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <assert.h>
std::atomic<bool> x,y;
std::atomic<int> z;
void write_x_then_y()
{
  x.store(true,std::memory_order_relaxed);
  y.store(true,std::memory_order_relaxed);
}
void read_y_then_x()
{
  while(!y.load(std::memory_order_relaxed));
  if(x.load(std::memory_order_relaxed))
  ++z;
}
int main()
{
  x=false;
  y=false;
  z=0;
  std::thread a(write_x_then_y);
  std::thread b(read_y_then_x);
  a.join();
  b.join();
  assert(z.load()!=0);
}
```

As far as I know, in each single thread, `sequenced before` also means `happens before`. 
So in thread a the store to `x` happens before `y`, which means `x` should be modified before `y` and the result `x.store` should be visible before `y` is modified.

But in this example the author says that the store between `x` and `y` could be reordered, why? Does that violate the rule of `sequenced before` and `happens before`?

Comment: This might explain things about relaxed ordering https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order#Relaxed_ordering

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen sequenced before relationship does not prevent reordering? Then what's the usage of sequenced before?

Comment: `x.store` happens-before `y.store` and `y.load` happens-before `x.load` - but `x.store` doesn't happen-before `x.load`. Happens-before relationship is not necessarily transitive in the presence of relaxed operations; that's kind of their whole point.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik  but `y.store` happens before  `while(!y.load(std::memory_order_relaxed))` , so `x.store` hapeens before `x.load`?

Comment: The conclusion doesn't follow from the premise. Yes, `y.store` happens-before `y.load`. No, `x.store` does not happen-before `x.load`. You have a sequentially-consistent model of execution in your head - but relaxed operations violate that model; that's why they are called "relaxed", and that's why they are difficult to reason about.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik since `y.store` happens before `y.load==true`, and happens before relationship is trasitive, why doesn't `x.store` happens before `x.load`?

Comment: Again, happens-before relationship is **not** in general transitive. In particular, it is not transitive in the presence of relaxed operations. Would it be too much to ask for you to read a comment in full before responding?

Comment: The **Concurrency in Action** says "It’s also a transitive relation: if A inter-thread happens-before B and B interthread
happens-before C, then A inter-thread happens-before C.".

Comment: *happens-before* and *inter-thread happens-before* are two different relations. Here, `y.load` does not inter-thread happens-before `x.load` (since both are on the same thread).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik What's the differences between happens before and inter-thread happens before?

Comment: http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.multithread#intro.races-10

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Your linkage says they are not different relations, inter-thread happens before belongs to happens before.

Comment: They are different relations, where one is a subset of the other. The subset is transitive; the superset is not. In particular, if `A` inter-thread happens-before `B` and `B` is sequenced-before `C`, this doesn't necessarily mean that `A` happens-before `C` (even though `A` happens-before `B` and `B` happens-before `C`).